# How to permanently remove update for Gwibber Facebook plugin

Tags: gwibber, facebook

I do not use facebook and do not want to add the Gwibber update for facebook that was recently added. I have facebook blocked in opendns but I want to keep from adding this plugin. How do I make the update go away so I do not have to add it? I am using Ubuntu 12.04. If I cannot remove it, will it send my info to facebook?

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then type/paste

```
sudo apt-get remove gwibber-service-facebook
```

should do it.

Comment: Thank you.  I used sudo apt-get purge gwibber-service-facebook instead of remove. I suppose there isn't a lot of difference but we prefer to avoid facebook.  I know others use facebook and we may reconsider but this answer was helpful.